# Inconsistent behavior in Expression.PropertyOrField

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, linq-expressions

[image: From NunitTest]

First expression passes, but second does not.. Error is

**AmbigiouseMatchExeption**

Anyone knows why field and propery of a class behaves inconsistly? 
How to fix it?

Comment: Consider editing your tags...your code is VB and not C#

Comment: One step closer...

    GetType(Inherited(Of String)).GetField("field1")  
    GetType(Inherited(Of String)).GetProperty("Prop1")

First on is OK 2. is not

Comment: Yeah, the inconsistency is in the reflection `GetField` / `GetProperty` API, not in the `Expression` code. The only way to "fix" it is to not use it and make your own replacement.

Comment: Please post your code as *text* rather than as a screenshot. It's very hard to read at the moment. Ideally, provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Expression.PropertyOrField` method uses `GetProperty(string,BindingFlags)` to lookup the property. This function doesn't appear to implement name hiding, whereas the corresponding `GetField(string,BindingFlags)` does.

You will need to use `GetProperties` and pick out the property you want, then use the `Expression.Property` overload that takes a `PropertyInfo`.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you that are interested ...
It fails on line

`GetType(Inherited(Of String)).GetProperty("Prop1")`

```
Imports System.Linq.Expressions
Imports NUnit.Framework

<TestFixture> Public Class ExpressionTEst

<Test> Public Sub GetOvrriddenProperyInExpression()

    Dim ex = Expression.PropertyOrField(Expression.Constant(Nothing, GetType(Inherited(Of String))), "field1")
    Dim ex2 = Expression.PropertyOrField(Expression.Constant(Nothing, GetType(Inherited(Of String))), "t2")

    GetType(Inherited(Of String)).GetField("field1")
    GetType(Inherited(Of String)).GetProperty("Prop1")

    Dim ex3 = Expression.PropertyOrField(Expression.Constant(Nothing, GetType(Inherited(Of String))), "Prop1")

End Sub

Public Class Base
    Public field1 As Object
    Public Property Prop1 As Object

    Public Overridable Property t2 As String
End Class

Public Class Inherited(Of T)
    Inherits Base

    Public Overrides Property t2 As String
        Get
            Return MyBase.t2
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            MyBase.t2 = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Shadows field1 As T
    Public Shadows Property Prop1 As T

End Class
```

End Class

So as @NetMage and @IvanStoev says the inconsistency is in the GetField vs GetProperty

this piece of code solves it.. kind of

```
Expression memberValue = null;
            if (m.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property)
            {
                PropertyInfo propInfo = null;
                foreach(var p in m.DeclaringType.GetProperties())
                {
                    if (p.Name == m.Name)
                    {
                        //Just pick the first one. 
                        propInfo = p;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                memberValue = Expression.Property(Expression.Convert(valueObject, objType), propInfo);
            }
            else
            {
                memberValue = Expression.Field(Expression.Convert(valueObject, objType), m.Name);
            }
```